# How to use XCOPY Visual Studio Post Build Command with RELATIVE paths

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget, xcopy

I am working on a visual studio project that has a post build event that copies the compiled DLLs in to another folder.

The X copy command looks like this:

```
XCOPY "$(TargetDir)*" "C:\Projects\AsoRockX\AsoRock.Web\bin" /S /Y
```

The problem I have is another developer is now working on this project and he can not put the project on his C: drive. He can only put it on his D: so the project fails to build.

How can I change that command so it looks for a relative path?

Comment: what does this have to do with nuget?  Anyway have you tried changing `c:\...` to `$(TargetDir)..\..\whatever`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know where you want to copy the files, but I would recommend the following command:

```
XCOPY $(targetDir)* $(solutionDir)\.. /S /Y
```

You need to make sure that the variables end or don't end which path-seperator (`\`).

I guess the folder above your `.sln` file is no longer inside the repository.

Comment: Yep, I worked that out in the end, easy when you know how :-)